# Parsing JSON in QML

Tags: javascript, json, qt, parsing, qml

The relevant Qt doc should be [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html). But it makes no mention of QML. Yet on many places on the net I find usage of functions like `JSON.parse` in QML JS. Is there such a function and how do I use it?

I'd just ask for a link to documentation but that's considered off-topic here.

Comment: The docs in Qt say that JS-related functions won't be part of the Qt docs and users should refer to the ECMAScript docs instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Parsing JSON in QML is no different than parsing [JSON in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp), because QML provides an environment based on ECMAScript ([link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html)) with some modifications especially for QML.

So you can use the in-built `JSON.parse()` function. The following example is possible in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var JsonString = '{"a":"A whatever, run","b":"B fore something happens"}';
        var JsonObject= JSON.parse(JsonString);

        //retrieve values from JSON again
        var aString = JsonObject.a;
        var bString = JsonObject.b;

        console.log(aString);
        console.log(bString);
    }
}
```

And this is the reason why the Qt docs don't state anything about this particular function:

> The standard ECMAScript built-ins are not explicitly documented in the QML documentation. For more information on their use, please refer to the ECMA-262 5th edition standard or one of the many online JavaScript reference and tutorial sites, such as the W3Schools JavaScript Reference (JavaScript Objects Reference section)

[Source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html)