# Qt reading data from JSON file to use in a .ui.qml file

Tags: json, qt, parsing, qml

I'm new to Qt and QML. I have a .ui.qml file that displays my graphics. I have a json file saved into the same file directory. I'm wondering how i can access the data in the json file and insert it's values into specific text boxes in the .ui.qml file? Trying to use QML to do this first and C++ if that is too hard.

Comment: The key words would be `parse json qml` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900383/parsing-json-in-qml/41900561 f.e. has a solution for that.

For using c++/qt this would be the way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075951/minimal-example-on-how-to-read-write-and-print-qjson-code-with-qjsondocument/61286325#61286325